# How to pass input to execSync

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm having difficulty passing input to execSync. For context, I'm calling an api that runs the following bit of code:

```
  fs.writeFileSync("compile.py", "input('How are you doing?: ')");

  const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;
  const options = {
    input: "good",
  };
  const pythonProcess = execSync("python3 compile.py", options);
  return res.json({ message: pythonProcess.toString() });
```

I expect the output to be `How are you doing? good`, but instead I just receive:

```
 "message": "How are you dong?: \n"
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm not sure where to begin. Is execSync the best method to handle this type of operation?

Comment: You don't show the code for your python `compile.py` so perhaps the issue is there?

Answer (score 0):

Your program works. You just needed to modify the python script to print the result:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import {execSync} from 'child_process';

fs.writeFileSync("compile.py", "print (input('How are you doing?: '))");
const pythonProcess = execSync("python3 compile.py", {
    input: "good",
});
console.log(pythonProcess.toString('utf-8'));
```

---

There is a case where using `execSync` will not work and that's the case where the program you are running is ignoring stdin and directly accessing the attached tty.

For example:

```
import {execSync} from 'child_process';

process.env.GPGKEY_FILE='/tmp/tmp.lIrACy7A3s.pgp';
process.env.GPGKEY_PASS='foobar';

const message = execSync(`gpg --export-secret-key --armor
                    --no-default-keyring --keyring=${process.env.GPGKEY_FILE}
                    --pinentry-mode=loopback`.replace(/\s+/g, ' '), {
                    input: process.env.GPGKEY_PASS,
});

console.log(message.toString('utf-8'));
```

I was having issues with the above because `gpg` kept trying to directly read from the tty rather than from stdin. The solution was to supply the `--passphrase-fd=0` option to the gpg command.

---

Here is another example of a program which will ignore its stdin and read from the tty directly (in bash):

```bash
exec {fd}<>$(tty)
read -u $fd -p 'hello? ' resp < <(echo "hi")
```

When you run the above program, you will see `"hello? "` printed to the terminal, and you will be prompted for input. After you press enter, the value of `$resp` will be whatever you had typed instead of `hi`.